# How to ALTER CHANNEL in C++?

Tags: c++, ibm-mq

[IBM's documentation on ALTER CHANNEL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q085170_.htm) goes to commendable length explaining the various available alterations, but does not offer a single *example* -- certainly not for C++-users.

Suppose, I want to change the `MCAUSER` from the default (OS username) to another string, what would the function-call look like?

Comment: @MoragHughson gives a good answer if you want to set the MCAUSER parameter on a channel, but are you perhaps asking how to authenticate as a different user than your application is running as (the OS username)?  If that is the case it would be helpful to have some additional information such as the version of MQ the queue manager is running and if it is v8.0 or later a display of the `AUTHINFO` object that is pointed to by the queue managers `CONNAUTH` parameter.

Comment: Yes, this is, what I'm looking for. My client is using MQ SDK 7.5.0 -- I don't know, what the server is using...

Comment: Being able to authenticate is a function of the queue manager version and configuration.

Comment: I can connect from the same machine as one Unix user, but not as another. My own code makes no effort of supplying the username currently -- the client library must be taking it from the OS. I'm sure, it is possible to set the username explicitly.

Comment: @Morag-Hughson, do you concur with Josh's assessment?

Comment: With out of the box IBM MQ it is not possible in C++ without the server being at v8.0 or later with CONNAUTH configured with ADOPTCTX(YES) to specify an arbitrary user. Essentially there is no security configured on the server side now. All you have to do is run mq as a user name that is allowed and you are in. (Reposted comment to fix typo)

Comment: Note v7.5 went out of support in 2018.  Use 9.2.0.1 (the latest) of possible.   This won't help your problem but is always a good idea to keep up to date.

Comment: CONNAUTH added in v8.0 on the queue manager side is what you are looking for. This allows you to send a username and password to the server to be validated. Another method is you present a cert and the server would be configured to map this to a MCAUSER. You could cause your program to run as a different user, sudo or power broker or SETUID on Unix, runas or the ImpersonateLoggedOnUser function on windows. But you description of how it currently works still points out that the MQ server is just "taking your word for it" on what your user name is.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you link to in your question is the MQSC command reference. This is designed for scripts.

Please also note that the default value of a channel's MCAUSER field is actually blank, not the OS username. Because it is blank, then in the case of a SVRCONN channel, when a client application connects, the OS username flowed from the client, will be used for the MCAUSER for that running instance. You cannot change this behaviour using ALTER CHANNEL from your client application. I note this, in case this is the reason you are thinking to use ALTER CHANNEL.

If you want to write a program to make a change to an IBM MQ object, such as a channel, you would instead want to make use of a different, but equivalent interface called the Programmable Command Format (PCF). The equivalent command reference page is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q086930_.htm).

There is an example C++ PCF sample [here](https://www.capitalware.com/mq_code_cplusplus.html) - look for **SrvPCF**

In short, psuedo-code, you would write a program as follows:-

```
MQCONN(Qmgr-name)
MQOPEN(Reply-Q)
Build PCF message for MQCMD_CHANGE_CHANNEL
          with MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME
          with MQIACH_CHANNEL_TYPE
          with MQCACH_MCA_USER_ID
MQPUT1(PCF Message to SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE)
MQGET(wait for reply on Reply-Q to say whether it worked or not)
```

Comment: Thanks, but -- as @JoshMC suspected -- what I'm looking for is to set a different username, when connecting to remote server. My client -- using MQ SDK 7.5.0 is getting authorization error, when connecting to the same server from the same host as one user, but not as another...

Comment: @MikhailT. - I suspected as much also, hence the second paragraph in my answer. Can you use runas?

Comment: Appreciated. So, can I ask my client (version 7.5.0) to provide a different username to the server, or is this another feature no one has asked for before? I tried calling the `setUserId("desireduser")` methods on both the queue- and the channel-objects in my program, and, although both methods return `true`, I'm still getting authorization error.

Comment: If you use the OS feature runas that is how you run a program as if it were run as a different user.

Comment: Things like `runas` and `sudo` actually change my effective UID to the target - which not only requires local authorization, but has other nasty effects (prevents tracing/debugging by the original user, etc). How does the client code determine its username? By `getuid()` or `geteuid()`? By examining an environment variable (such as `$USER`)?

Comment: @MikhailT. Try a `strace` and see, this is not documented but would be easy to observe in a strace output.